# get previous and present selected value of the dropdown using chosen in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-chosen

I have a drop down

```
 <select name="manager" class="managerchosen-select-deselect" >
    <option value="" >Select  Manager</option>
    <option value="xyz"> XYZ </option>
    <option value="abc"> ABC</option>
    <option value="pqr"> PQR</option>
  </select>
```

I need 2 alerts based on 2 events on this drop down. First is When I click on the drop down the previous value must be shown in alert and the second is on change of drop down the present selected value is to be displayed in alert.

I have tried the following jquery code, but I am getting only one alert i.e on change. I am not getting alert for on click. Why?

```
    var lastvalue;
   $(".manager").bind("click", function(e){
     lastValue = $(this).val(); 
     alert(lastvalue);
     }).bind("change", function(e){ alert('value changed');
     changeConfirmation = confirm("Are You Sure?");
   if (changeConfirmation) {
      //proceed
   } else {
      $(this).val(lastValue);
   }
   });
```

Comment: your selector seems wrong. add a class 'manager' to select tag. I can see there is only one class to select so far 'managerchosen-select-deselect'.

Answer (score 1):

define them separately

```
    var lastvalue;
   $(".manager").bind("click", function(e){
     lastValue = $(this).val(); 
     alert(lastvalue);
     });
   $(".manager").bind("change", function(e){ 
     alert('value changed');
     changeConfirmation = confirm("Are You Sure?");
     if (changeConfirmation) {
      //proceed
     } else {
      $(this).val(lastValue);
     }
   });
```

You can use defaultValue to retrieve the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Considering yours typo mistake in declaring select class `managerchosen-select-deselect` to be `manager chosen-select-deselect`, You may want to try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wsejec8L/

```
(function () {
    var lastValue;    
 $(".manager").on('click', function () {
       lastValue = this.value;
 }).change(function() {
          alert('Previous value: ' + lastValue);
          alert('Current value: ' +this.value);
          lastValue = this.value;
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have `manager` class on your select element. You can use `focus` event rather than `click` as user can press tab and reach to dropdown and then change the value using arrow keys, click will not work in this use case.

```
(function () {
    var lastValue;    
    $(".manager").on('focus', function () {
        lastValue = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        alert('Previous value: ' + lastValue);
        alert('Current value: ' +this.value);
        lastValue = this.value;
    });
})();
```

updated fiddle (using focus):
http://jsfiddle.net/wsejec8L/1/